# Move up/down a model in a backbone collection

Tags: jquery, backbone.js

I am trying to change the order of models in my backbone collection on a click of button.

I am doing this in my code:

```
collectionForJsonElement= Backbone.Collection.extend({
            //set model for collection
            model: modelForJsonElement,
            //set filterBy function to Collection
            filterBy: function(searchTerm) {
                filtered= this.filter(function(model) {
                    return ((model.get('text').toString()).indexOf(searchTerm.toString()) !== -1);
                });
                return new collectionForJsonElement(filtered);
            },
            //set moveUp function to Collection
            moveUp: function(model) { // I see move up as the -1
                var index = this.indexOf(model);
                if (index > 0) {
                    this.remove(model, {silent: true}); // silence this to stop excess event triggers
                    this.add(model, {at: index-1});
                }
            },
            //set moveDown function to COllection
            moveDown: function(model) { // I see move up as the -1              
                var index = this.indexOf(model);
                if (index < this.models.length) {
                    this.remove(model, {silent: true});
                    this.add(model, {at: index});
                }
            }
        });
```

When I am trying to move up, it is working fine. My model index position is changing by -1. However when i am trying to move down, My model goes to the last position.

For ex, in my backbone collection, i have 3 model

```
One
Two
Three
```

If i select three, and click on move up button, new order for model in collection is changed to:

```
One
Three
Two
```

However if i select one, and click move down button, new order for model is changed to:

```
Three
Two
One
```

I cant figure out why it is not working right in move down case.
Can someone give me insight what wrong is going here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are putting the model back to its original position. in your moveDown method.

well, why don't you just try to swap positions of the models instead of removing it and add it back?

```
moveUp: function(model) {
  var index = this.indexOf(model);

  if (index > 0){
    this.swap(index, index-1);
  }
},

moveDown: function(model) {
  var index = this.indexOf(model);

  if (index < this.models.length) {
    this.swap(index, index+1);
  }
},

swap: function (indexA, indexB) {
  this.models[indexA] = this.models.splice(indexB, 1, this.models[indexA])[0];
}
```

<strike>well i'm still using remove and add here cuz we are allowing moveUp
the first one or moveDown the last one. :)</strike>

**EDIT:** 
i just realized in your original code you ignore the case of when the model is the first one (in moveUp) or the last one (in moveDown)

updated my code :)

Comment: Will it return an array or a backbone collection.

I tried using the code, after moving down, when i try to call method toJSON() to collection, it throw me an error
**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'toJSON' of undefined.**

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/bFeb8/   please check this jsfiddle. I don't see anything wrong with it, and I'm able to use toJSON after moving the models. (open your console to see results after each move).

Comment: Thank you. I think i know my mistake now. Your fiddle was a great help :D